MySQL Query Extremely Slow, Need Optimization Suggestions
I have a MySQL query as follows, which involves joining multiple tables, and includes subqueries, different aggregate functions, and filtering conditions. When I execute this query in the production environment, it runs extremely slowly, taking several minutes or even longer to complete. Could the experts please provide optimization suggestions to help speed up the execution of this query?
My current SQL requirement is to query combo_info, then query the usage count for each combo in the orders, the last used time, the number of parameters where role=0 for each combo (counting duplicates only once), the total number of non-duplicate parameters for each combo, how many non-duplicate (in the same combo, the same parameter value is counted only once) parameter values were added when configuring the combo (the relationship is parameter item:parameter value -> 1:n), and the total number of non-duplicate parameter values used for each combo in the orders.
select bci.id,
       bci.customer_id                                                     customerId,
       bci.combo_name                                                      comboName,
       bci.combo_code                                                      comboCode,
       bci.combo_describe                                                  comboDescribe,
       bci.create_time                                                     createTime,
       c.last_create_time                                                  lastUseTime,
       ifnull(c.count1, 0)                                                 useCount,
       bci.robot                                                           robot,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(bcpvr.parameters_value_id)) AS                comCount,
       count(distinct case when bcpr.role = 0 then bcpr.parameters_id end) editCount,
       count(distinct bcpr.parameters_id)                                  allCount,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(bc.parameters_value_id))    AS                cupCount
from bst_combo_info bci
         left join (select count(field1) as count1, field1, MAX(create_time) as last_create_time
                    from bst_order_info boi
                    where field1 is not null
                      and field1 != ''
                    group by field1) as c on c.field1 = bci.id
         inner join bst_combo_parameter_record bcpr on bcpr.combo_id = bci.id and bcpr.del_status = 'Y'
         inner join bst_combo_prarmeter_value_record bcpvr on bcpvr.combo_id = bci.id and bcpvr.del_status = 'Y'
         inner join bst_combo_detail bcd on bcd.combo_id = bci.id and bcd.is_vaild = 'Y'
         inner join bst_customer_parameters_value_record bc
                    on bc.customer_id = bci.customer_id and bc.product_id = bcd.product_id and bc.del_status = 'Y'
WHERE (bci.combo_status <> -100 and bci.is_vaild = 'Y')
group by bci.id
order by useCount desc, lastUseTime desc
limit 10

bst_combo_info_index：
create index idx
    on bst_combo_info (id, combo_code, customer_id);

create index idx_status
    on bci (combo_status);

bst_order_info_index:

create index idx_combo_id
    on bst_order_info (field1);

create index idx_delstatus
    on bst_order_info (del_status);


create index idx_order_status
    on bst_order_info (order_status);

bst_combo_parameter_record_index:
create index idx
    on bst_combo_parameter_record (combo_id, customer_id, product_id, parameters_id, id, del_status);

bst_combo_prarmeter_value_record_index:
create index idx
    on bst_combo_prarmeter_value_record (combo_id, customer_id, parameters_id, parameters_value_id, id, del_status,
                                         product_id);

bst_combo_detail_index:
create index idx_combo_id
    on bst_combo_detail (combo_id, customer_id, product_id, id, del_status);

bst_customer_parameters_value_record_index:
create index id
    on bst_customer_parameters_value_record (id);

create index idx
    on bst_customer_parameters_value_record (customer_id, product_id, parameters_id, parameters_value_id);

create index idx_customer_id
    on bst_customer_parameters_value_record (parameters_value_id, customer_id, product_id);

create index price
    on bst_customer_parameters_value_record (customer_id, parameters_value_id);

EXPLAIN Execution Plan:
+--+-----------+----------+----------+-----+------------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+-----+--------+--------------------------------------------+
|id|select_type|table     |partitions|type |possible_keys     |key         |key_len|ref                    |rows |filtered|Extra                                       |
+--+-----------+----------+----------+-----+------------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+-----+--------+--------------------------------------------+
|1 |PRIMARY    |bci       |null      |index|PRIMARY,idx_id,idx|PRIMARY     |146    |null                   |6293 |9       |Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort|
|1 |PRIMARY    |bc        |null      |ref  |price,idx         |idx         |147    |bst_sys.bci.customer_id|155  |10      |Using where                                 |
|1 |PRIMARY    |bcd       |null      |ref  |idx_combo_id      |idx_combo_id|147    |bst_sys.bci.id         |35   |1       |Using index condition; Using where          |
|1 |PRIMARY    |bcpr      |null      |ref  |idx               |idx         |147    |bst_sys.bci.id         |75   |10      |Using index condition                       |
|1 |PRIMARY    |bcpvr     |null      |ref  |idx               |idx         |147    |bst_sys.bci.id         |105  |10      |Using where; Using index                    |
|1 |PRIMARY    |<derived2>|null      |ref  |<auto_key0>       |<auto_key0> |147    |bst_sys.bci.id         |10   |100     |null                                        |
|2 |DERIVED    |boi       |null      |range|idx_combo_id      |idx_combo_id|147    |null                   |61829|100     |Using index condition                       |
+--+-----------+----------+----------+-----+------------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+-----+--------+--------------------------------------------+


run this select count(*) :6070 rows times:2s 857ms
select count(*)
from bst_combo_info bci
         left join (
    select count(field1) as count1, field1, MAX(create_time) as last_create_time
    from bst_order_info boi
    where field1 is not null
      and field1 != ''
    group by field1) as c on c.field1 = bci.id
where bci.combo_status not in (-100) and bci.is_vaild = 'Y'

run this select count(*) : 2425818 rows times: 6s 400ms
select count(*)
from bst_combo_info bci
         left join (
    select count(field1) as count1, field1, MAX(create_time) as last_create_time
    from bst_order_info boi
    where field1 is not null
      and field1 != ''
    group by field1) as c on c.field1 = bci.id
         inner join bst_combo_parameter_record bcpr on bcpr.combo_id = bci.id and bcpr.del_status = 'Y'
where bci.combo_status not in (-100) and bci.is_vaild = 'Y'

I had tried to split it into subqueries for execution, but the results were still very slow. It took five minutes and still didn't get the results:
select bci.*,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(bc.parameters_value_id)) AS cupCount
from (select bci.*,
             COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(bcpvr.parameters_value_id)) AS comCount
      from (select bci.*,
                   count(distinct case when bcpr.role = 0 then bcpr.parameters_id end) editCount,
                   count(distinct bcpr.parameters_id)                                  allCount
            from (select bci.id,
                         bci.customer_id,
                         bci.combo_name      comboName,
                         bci.combo_code      comboCode,
                         bci.combo_describe  comboDescribe,
                         bci.create_time     createTime,
                         c.last_create_time  lastUseTime,
                         ifnull(c.count1, 0) useCount,
                         bci.robot           robot


                  from bst_combo_info bci
                           left join (select count(field1) as count1, field1, MAX(create_time) as last_create_time
                                      from bst_order_info boi
                                      where field1 is not null
                                        and field1 != ''
                                      group by field1) as c on c.field1 = bci.id
                  WHERE (bci.combo_status <> -100 and bci.is_vaild = 'Y')) bci
                     inner join bst_combo_parameter_record bcpr on bcpr.combo_id = bci.id and bcpr.del_status = 'Y'
            group by bci.id) bci
               inner join bst_combo_prarmeter_value_record bcpvr on bcpvr.combo_id = bci.id and bcpvr.del_status = 'Y'
      group by bci.id) bci
         inner join bst_combo_detail bcd on bcd.combo_id = bci.id and bcd.is_vaild = 'Y'
         inner join bst_customer_parameters_value_record bc
                    on bc.customer_id = bci.customer_id and bc.product_id = bcd.product_id and bc.del_status = 'Y'
group by bci.id
order by useCount
        desc, lastUseTime desc
limit 10

EXPLAIN Execution Plan:
+--+-----------+----------+----------+-----+------------------+------------+-------+--------------------------------------+------+--------+--------------------------------------------+
|id|select_type|table     |partitions|type |possible_keys     |key         |key_len|ref                                   |rows  |filtered|Extra                                       |
+--+-----------+----------+----------+-----+------------------+------------+-------+--------------------------------------+------+--------+--------------------------------------------+
|1 |PRIMARY    |bcd       |null      |ALL  |idx_combo_id      |null        |null   |null                                  |195805|10      |Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort|
|1 |PRIMARY    |<derived2>|null      |ref  |<auto_key1>       |<auto_key1> |146    |bst_sys.bcd.combo_id                  |15    |100     |Using where                                 |
|1 |PRIMARY    |bc        |null      |ref  |price,idx         |idx         |294    |bci.customer_id,bst_sys.bcd.product_id|66    |10      |Using where                                 |
|2 |DERIVED    |<derived3>|null      |ALL  |null              |null        |null   |null                                  |42654 |100     |Using filesort                              |
|2 |DERIVED    |bcpvr     |null      |ref  |idx               |idx         |147    |bci.id                                |105   |10      |Using where; Using index                    |
|3 |DERIVED    |bci       |null      |index|PRIMARY,idx_id,idx|PRIMARY     |146    |null                                  |6293  |9       |Using where                                 |
|3 |DERIVED    |bcpr      |null      |ref  |idx               |idx         |147    |bst_sys.bci.id                        |75    |10      |Using index condition                       |
|3 |DERIVED    |<derived5>|null      |ref  |<auto_key0>       |<auto_key0> |147    |bst_sys.bci.id                        |10    |100     |null                                        |
|5 |DERIVED    |boi       |null      |range|idx_combo_id      |idx_combo_id|147    |null                                  |61832 |100     |Using index condition                       |
+--+-----------+----------+----------+-----+------------------+------------+-------+--------------------------------------+------+--------+--------------------------------------------+

I have tried splitting it into individual subqueries or separate queries, which did make it faster. However, the requirement is to count the lastUseTime, useCount, comCount, editCount, allCount, and cupCount of all bci data, and in actual use, the counted data needs to be sorted and filtered. So I have to put them all in one query and join them together. The effect is extremely poor.

You could start by turning most/all of your LEFT JOINs into INNER JOINs - as the WHERE clause is implicitly doing this anyway. If that doesn't fix the problem then start with one table and check the performance of that; then add the other tables one by one, checking and fixing the performance for each one in turn
